# Pegar valor no onclick js

Tags: javascript

Eu tenho a seguinte variavel:

```
var id = doc.data().cd_id ;
```

Já no JavaScript eu monto dinamicamente  o html:

```
"<button type='button' onclick='testeonclick(" + id + ")' class='btn btn-primary col-xs-12'>Editar Produto </button>"
```

Minha Função:

```
function testeonclick(id){
  alert(id);
}
```

Acontece o seguinte erro:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

O meu id possui o seguinte valor: 4eCj7NkX9liruvf8izgF

Comment: Apenas com as informações que aqui esta não é possível dizer aonde esta o erro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

falta aspas duplas, coloque-as escapando-as dessa forma

```
onclick='testeonclick(\"" + id + "\")'
```

**Teste**

```js
function testeonclick(id){
  alert(id);
}
var id = "4eCj7NkX9liruvf8izgF";

//erro
console.log("ERRADO \n<button type='button' onclick='testeonclick(" + id + ")' class='btn btn-primary col-xs-12'>Editar Produto </button>");

//correto
console.log("CORRETO \n<button type='button' onclick='testeonclick(\"" + id + "\")' class='btn btn-primary col-xs-12'>Editar Produto </button>");

document.write("<button type='button' onclick='testeonclick(\"" + id + "\")' class='btn btn-primary col-xs-12'>Editar Produto </button>");
```